# How to force this div to span the height of viewport?

Tags: html, css

This [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jD57S/) shows the problem.  I have not managed to prevent the `div0` div from "collapsing" its top margin with that of its sibling, `div1`.  (HTML below.)

I want `div0` to span the *entire viewport* vertically, and the red `rect` inside it to appear flush against the top left corner of the viewport.  (The placement of `div1` and its contents is exactly as desired, and should not be changed in any way.)

I have tried to disable the collapsing of margins by putting borders around both `div0` and `div1`, but, as the jsFiddle shows, this has made no difference.

Here's the relevant HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<body>
    <div id="div0">
        <svg id="svg0" width="50px" height="50px">
            <g>
                <rect x="0px" y="0px"
                      width="50px" height="50px" style="fill:red;"></rect>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>

    <div id="div1">
        <div id="div2">
            <svg id="svg1" width="100px" height="100px"></svg>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for you.  I added a `.wrapper` class, with a `absolute` `position`, to contain the elements and maintain elasticity in your document.  I also added `overflow: hidden` to your `div0` id to prevent the red `svg` `rect` from flowing outside of that containing `div`.

Here is an updated [>>>JSFiddle<<<](http://jsfiddle.net/nTuAE/3/)

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="div0">
        <svg id="svg0" width="50px" height="50px">
            <g>
                <rect x="0" y="0" width="50px" height="50px"></rect>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div id="div1">
        <div id="div2">
            <svg id="svg1" width="100px" height="100px"></svg>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
#div0 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#div1 {
    margin-top: 20px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    background: lightgray;
    min-height: 27px;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}
#div2 {
    background: black;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
rect {
    fill: red;
}
```

Comment: interesting: your solution works, but not for the reason you describe, because in your CSS you use the selector `.wrapper`, whereas in your HTML you have `id=wrapper`, not `class=wrapper`.  IOW, the CSS for `.wrapper` has no effect whatsoever.  I eventually discoverd (and just posted) a solution that (I think) is closer to the mark.

Answer (score 0):

```
#div0 {
height:100vh;
}
```

You can use the vh for viewport height.

Comment: interesting idea, but did you test it in the jsFiddle I provided?  (that's the point of providing a jsFiddle, you know...)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the solution: comment out the `position:relative` in the CSS for `body`.  This is illustrated in [this revision](http://jsfiddle.net/jD57S/3/) of the original fiddle.  Notice that the only difference between this and the original fiddle is the commented-out line just mentioned.

(I'm ashamed to say that I found this solution by blind trial-and-error; I have no idea of why the new version works and the original one didn't.)